# Get address of symbol at runtime in kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am writing a **kernel module** and the **kaslr** is enabled
What is the function that I should use such that I give it a symbol and it returns back the address of that symbol at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Linux, `kallsyms_lookup_name()` will lookup a symbol and return an address, defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/kernel/kallsyms.c#L201).